# A problem with <openssl/applink.c> with C++

Tags: c++, openssl

update 
I find the method to solve this, just add the "-fpermissive" in the compile option

---

I need use the applink.c in C++ so I use

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <openssl/applink.c>
#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

to import this file.
But it doesn't work.
And when I build the programme, it return many errors like:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/OPENSS~1/include/openssl/applink.c:104:47: error: invalid conversion from 'void* (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
  104 |         OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDIN] = app_stdin;
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                               |
      |                                               void* (*)()
C:/PROGRA~1/OPENSS~1/include/openssl/applink.c:105:48: error: invalid conversion from 'void* (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
  105 |         OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDOUT] = app_stdout;
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                |
      |                                                void* (*)()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you including a `*.c` file `<openssl/applink.c>` instead of building it and linking with it ?

Comment: Include **headers**, not source files.

Comment: Openssl builds `applink.c` and not `applink.h`.